# Agregar imagen de fondo a gráfico Polar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estaba practicando con polar y llegue a esto, ¿Es posible poner como fondo de gráfico (solo del gráfico) una imagen? En el ejemplo que pongo y por el que me guié [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119991/6388106) la imagen se pone pero como fondo de todo el plano.

(Si ejecutan el código se les va a descargar una imagen que es la que uso de fondo, si no quieren eso cambien donde dice url_imagen = '' y pongan la dirección de alguna que tengan)

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import pi
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import requests
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Cero': ['Uno'],
'Uno': [20],
'Dos': [30],
'Tres': [40],
'Cuatro': [50],
'Cinco': [60],
'Seis': [70],
'Siete': [80],
'Ocho': [90],
'Nueve': [100]
})

url_imagen = "https://store-images.s- 
microsoft.com/image/apps.6102.13510798887356280.9398b0dd-2ecf-4973-9380- 
576d1d374a25.92d12017-af9a-41ae-b97a-8213710cdb49? 
mode=scale&q=90&h=1080&w=1920"

nombre_local_imagen = "go.jpg"
imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(imagen)

def detalle(row, title):

    color = '#80cbc4'

    img = mpimg.imread('go.jpg')

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

    categories=list(df)[1:]
    N = len(categories)
    angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
    angles += angles[:1]
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

    ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color= "black", size=10)
    ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
    plt.yticks([25,50,75,100], ["25","50","75","100"], color="grey", size=8)
    plt.ylim(0,100)

    values=df.loc[row].drop('Cero').values.flatten().tolist()   
    values += values[:1]

    ax.plot(angles, values, color= "black", linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
    ax.fill(angles, values, color= color, alpha=0.9)

    axes_coords = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    ax_image = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords)
    ax_image.imshow(img, alpha=.5)
    ax_image.axis('off')

    plt.title(title, size=50, color= "black", y=1.1)
    plt.title(title, size=50, color= "black", y=1.1)
    my_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap("Set2", len(df.index))

detalle(row= row, title=df['Cero'][row])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en la linea ax_image = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords) agrego zorder= -99 se ve asi:

```
ax_image = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords, zorder= -99)
```

Necesito lo contrario, que la imagen solo se vea dentro del grafico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer añadiendo a la image un `clip_path()`, que sea un círculo colocado en el lugar adecuado. En este caso sería:

```
axes_coords = [0, 0, 1, 1]
ax_image = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords)
im = ax_image.imshow(img, alpha=.5)
ax_image.axis('off')

patch = matplotlib.patches.Circle((562,314), radius=215)
im.set_clip_path(patch)
```

Desgraciadamente los números mágicos `(563, 314)` para el centro y `215` para el radio los he tenido que sacar por ensayo y error. No sé cómo obtenerlos de forma automática. He intentado que el centro fuese la mitad de `im.get_size()`, pero no sale bien. Supongo que los ejes han transformado las coordenadas de algún modo, pero no doy con la forma de obtener estas dimensiones.

El resultado se ve así:

[image: Resultado]

## Actualización

¡Lo encontré! En lugar de crear un círculo "a mano" para hacer el clipping, pensé que mejor sería usar el que matplotlib ha usado para pintar sus ejes de coordenadas polares.

Con `ax.get_children()` se obtiene la lista de objetos que componen el plot, entre los que se hallan la línea poligonal de los datos, etiquetas de texto, etc. Uno de estos objetos es de tipo `matplotlib.patches.Wedge`, que es un sector circular (o también un círculo completo como en este caso). Basta extraer ese *patch* y usarlo para hacer el clip:

```
circle = [c for c in ax.get_children() if type(c) == matplotlib.patches.Wedge][0]
im.set_clip_path(circle)
```

### *Bonus*

Con un pequeño cambio puedes hacer que el clip sea sobre el polígono de datos:

```
clip = [c for c in ax.get_children() if type(c) == matplotlib.patches.Polygon][0]
im.set_clip_path(clip)
```

lo que resulta en:

[image: Resultado recortado a polígono]

Incluso puedes crear dos `ax_image`, ponerle una imagen diferente a cada uno así como un diferente clip_path, y jugar con su z-order, para obtener:

[image: Dos texturas]

Este es el código de la última figura:

```
title = "Uno"
color = '#80cbc4'

img = mpimg.imread('roca.jpg')
img2 = mpimg.imread('arena.jpg')


plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))

categories=list(df)[1:]
N = len(categories)
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color= "black", size=10)
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
plt.yticks([25,50,75,100], ["25","50","75","100"], color="grey", size=8)
plt.ylim(0,100)

values=df.loc[row].drop('Cero').values.flatten().tolist()   
values += values[:1]

ax.plot(angles, values, color= "black", linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
ax.fill(angles, values, color= color, alpha=0.9)

# Axes para las imágenes. El zorder pondrá la piedra delante de la arena
axes_coords = [0, 0, 1, 1]
ax_image = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords, zorder=2)
ax_image2 = plt.gcf().add_axes(axes_coords, zorder=1)
ax_image2.axis('off')
ax_image.axis('off')

# Fondo de arena recortado al círculo
im2 = ax_image2.imshow(img2, alpha=0.5)
clip = [c for c in ax.get_children() if type(c) == matplotlib.patches.Wedge][0]
im2.set_clip_path(clip)

# Fondo de piedra recortado al polígono
im = ax_image.imshow(img, alpha=.5)
clip = [c for c in ax.get_children() if type(c) == matplotlib.patches.Polygon][0]
im.set_clip_path(clip)

plt.title(title, size=50, color= "black", y=1.1)
plt.title(title, size=50, color= "black", y=1.1)

my_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap("Set2", len(df.index))
```

Comment: Espectacular! El que subí era de ejemplo el final es este creado en base a datos del dataset del fifa 2019 https://i.ibb.co/wyvcNjb/asd.png, también tuve el mismo problema que vos en las coordenadas al poner los ax.annotate así que fue a prueba y error hasta que el club, la nacionalidad y la edad quedaron donde están, porque se ve que va en espiral. Por si te interesa: github: https://github.com/juanspinelli/main/blob/master/Fifa/Analisis.ipynb debe (tiene) que tener 1000 errores y formas de optimizarlo pero recien estoy empezando con data science así que va queriendo.

Comment: Eh, @Juan, espectaculares también tus gráficos. Me alegra haber contribuído a su consecución. Un saludo!